# Set a host name alias in /etc/hosts?

Tags: dns, hostname, hosts

I'm having an issue relating to host names and SSL signing. The certificate signing process works fine if my host name is `puppet`. With the IP of the puppet master server being set in `/etc/hosts`.

I don't want to use the IP as it will likely change and I'll have to update `/etc/hosts` again.

Instead I point directly to the url but this causes additional issues relating to inconsistency in certificate names.

Is there anyway to set a host to url? E.g. something like the following in `/etc/hosts`:

```
example.com puppet
```

Comment: That's not an URL.  The format of that file should be `ip-address hostname alias(es)`.

Comment: No, `/etc/hosts` is used specifically to assign an IP address to a given set of hostnames.

Comment: Just use DNS instead.

Comment: @SatoKatsura can I do this to associate local host name puppet with a url?

Comment: Not until you understand what DNS does.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I know that DNS servers are used to associate public website names with IP addresses. I take it from your comment that if I do more reading on DNS and linux I can over-ride public DNS locally to forward hostname `puppet` to a url. Unsure because comment is a bit vague.

Comment: You need to understand the details of how certificates work (that's a long, very technical read), then you need to read about DNS views.  How exactly you can do what you want depends a lot on your exact setup.  Which is to say you should probably ask on a `puppet` forum.

Comment: When you reference puppet do you really want to connect to puppet.example.com ? if so, just setting a `search domain` option to example.com in /etc/resolv.conf should do that for you (if it can't find puppet via hosts or dns it tries puppet.example.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anyway to set a host to url? E.g. something like the following in /etc/hosts

That is not a URL. Its a hostname. The point of the /etc/hosts file is that it provides an *alternative* to DNS for resolving hostnames to addresses.

The files nameservice (the bit of code that sits between your application and the /etc/hosts file) does not support this.

If you have your own nameserver then you could setup a CNAME record pointing the name puppet to example,com

Alternatively you could write a script to capture the DNS address of example.com and append it to a template to create the hosts file (at boot up or at intervals).

Or just fix your certificates.